# What is the difference between a new database and a new measurement inside a database?

Tags: database, influxdb

I am wondering when do I create a new database vs when do I add a new measurement inside an existing database in InfluxDB.

To answer this I guess I need to know the technical differences between the two.

Currently I know that on a DB level we can set a retention policy (as per the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/manage-database/#create-retention-policies-with-create-retention-policy)), whereas on a measurement levels this is not possible.

Besides this, are there other things to consider? Possibly things which are in the backed and may affect performance? E.g. I guess it's not a good practice to create a separate DB with one measurement every time, but I don't understand the implication to the performance of this.

Answer (score 0):

Database is a collection of measurements. If you delete(drop/remove) a database all the measurements under that will be deleted.

Measurement is a table where you store the data. You can call it as a container for tags, field & time column. Measurements are equivalent of `Tables` in SQL & `Collection` in MongoDB.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I know this much as well, but I don't know when to consider adding a new measurement vs adding a new DB with a measurement inside. As I state in the question - what are the logical and performance implications to this?